# How can I change background without delay in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm designing a website and I'm using following javascript to change background of div in:

```
<script>
    var newback = document.getElementById("introImage");
    var images = ["img/intro.jpg" , "img/intro2.jpg" , "img/intro3.jpg"]
        var i = 0;
        setInterval(function() {
            newback.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + images[i] + ")";
            i = i + 1;
            if (i == images.length) {
                i =  0;
            }
        }, 5000);
</script>
```

It works fine, but there is a problem. When I open the webpage, next bacground image is downloaded after 5 second, so first transition to each image is slow dependent on the internet speed.

Is it possible to download these images at the beginning?

Comment: Are you using jQuery lib ?

Comment: do a search for image preload

Comment: this link shows the simple concept of preloading images: http://www.thonky.com/javascript-and-css-guide/javascript-image-preload

Comment: Thanks, preloading worked.